# Jquery button img change not working in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The button img changes perfectly fine in chrome however in IE and Firefox it seems the code gets completely ignored.

```
$(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    $("#sortButton").bind('click', function(){
        if (counter == 0) {
            counter = 1;
            $("#sortButton").attr('src', '../../images/sortbttn.png');
        }
        else {
            counter = 0;
            $("#sortButton").attr('src', '../../images/sortbttnclosed.png');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle sortbutton" type="button" id="Button1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <img id="sortButton" src="../../images/sortbttnclosed.png" />
</button>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Toggling an image src with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057513/toggling-an-image-src-with-jquery)

Comment: When you inspect the element with the browser dev tools, do you see a correct path to the image?

Comment: Yes the path to the images are correct.

Comment: When you click the `img`, what's actually receiving the `click event` is the `button` wrapping it.

Comment: Yes the button is wrapping it and receiving the click event .

Comment: Yes, and both FF and IE are not reflecting the click to the `img` within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of binding click of img under button use this

```js
$("#Button1").bind('click', function(){
  ^ change this
```

i have tested it working in, every thing else is fine in your code, however you can optimized the code a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

The method `.on()` should be used instead of `.bind()` if you're on `jQuery` > 1.7.
The `img` is wrapped with a `button`, so the best way is to handle the click event in this element.

You can also dry out a bit your code making it simpler:

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortButton").closest('button').on('click', function () {
        var img1 = '../../images/sortbttn.png';
        var img2 = '../../images/sortbttnclosed.png';
        var currentImg = $('#sortButton', this).attr('src');

        $('#sortButton', this).attr('src', currentImg === img1 ? img2 : img1);
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/oqb3hn9p/1/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use jQuerys `on` instead of `bind`.

"As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document." - [Source](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Second, this might be a caching issue. Try to hide and show the element again:

```
$(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    $("#sortButton").on('click', function(){
        if (counter == 0) {
            counter = 1;
            $("#sortButton").attr('src', '../../images/sortbttn.png').hide().show();
        }
        else {
            counter = 0;
            $("#sortButton").attr('src', '../../images/sortbttnclosed.png').hide().show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change from `#sortButton` to `#Button1` ! Link to jsFiddle, [tested with IE](http://jsfiddle.net/poeo4by5/4/)

```js
$(function () {
    var counter = 0;
    $("#Button1").click( function () {
        if (counter == 0) {
            counter = 1;
            $("#sortButton").attr('src', 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/8/b/a/11971212312045077795webmichl_powerbutton_2_states_(_on_off_).svg.med.png');
        } else {
            counter = 0;
            $("#sortButton").attr('src', 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/S/4/F/9/3/r/round-button-off-md.png');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle sortbutton" type="button" id="Button1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <img id="sortButton" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/S/4/F/9/3/r/round-button-off-md.png" />
</button>
```