# Responsive Circle images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make an responsive web page.
I have used this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813573/position-icons-into-circle) and [answer](http://dabblet.com/gist/3864650), to form mine icon circle for this project.
But I would like to make it more responsive, because I need to wrap some jQuery toggle() inside.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="circle-container">
        <div class="row">

            <span data-scrollreveal="enter top, wait 1.0s">
              <a href="#" class="center hvr-grow"><img src="img/specialoffers.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="">
              </a>
            </span>

            <span data-scrollreveal="enter right, wait 1.2s">
              <a href="#" class="deg0"><img src="img/circle/special.png" class="img-circle" alt=""></a>
            </span>

            <span data-scrollreveal="enter right, wait 1.4s">
              <a href="#" class="deg45"><img src="img/specialoffers.jpg" class="img-circle" alt=""></a>
            </span>

            <span data-scrollreveal="enter right, wait 1.6s">
              <a href="#" class="deg135"><img src="img/specialoffers.jpg" class="img-circle" alt=""></a>
            </span>

            <span data-scrollreveal="enter left, wait 1.8s">
              <a href="#" class="deg180"><img src="img/specialoffers.jpg" class="img-circle" alt=""></a>
            </span>

            <span data-scrollreveal="enter left, wait 2.0s">
              <a href="#" class="deg225"><img src="img/specialoffers.jpg" class="img-circle" alt=""></a>   
 /* Position icons into sircle */
.circle-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 35em;
    height: 35em;
    padding: 2.8em; /*= 2em * 1.4 (2em = half the width of an img, 1.4 = sqrt(2))*/
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 1.75em auto 0;
}

.circle-container a {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    width: 6em; height: 6em;
    margin: -2em; /* 2em = 4em/2 */ /* half the width */
}

.circle-container img {
    display: block; width: 100%;
}

.deg0 { transform: translate(18em); } /* 12em= half the width of the wrapper */
.deg45 { transform: rotate(45deg) translate(18em) rotate(-45deg); }
.deg135 { transform: rotate(135deg) translate(18em) rotate(-135deg); }
.deg180 { transform: translate(-18em); }
.deg225 { transform: rotate(225deg) translate(18em) rotate(-225deg); }
.deg315 { transform: rotate(315deg) translate(18em) rotate(-315deg); }

.circle-container a.deg45:hover, a.deg45:activate { img-size: 150%; }
                  </span>

                  <span data-scrollreveal="enter left, wait 2.2s">
                    <a href="#" class="deg315"><img src="img/specialoffers.jpg" class="img-circle" alt=""></a>
                  </span>


              </div>
          </div><!--end circle-container-->
      </div>
```

CSS for this div:

```
/* Position icons into sircle */
.circle-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 35em;
    height: 35em;
    padding: 2.8em; /*= 2em * 1.4 (2em = half the width of an img, 1.4 = sqrt(2))*/
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 1.75em auto 0;
}

.circle-container a {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    width: 6em; height: 6em;
    margin: -2em; /* 2em = 4em/2 */ /* half the width */
}

.circle-container img {
    display: block; width: 100%;
}

.deg0 { transform: translate(18em); } /* 12em= half the width of the wrapper */
.deg45 { transform: rotate(45deg) translate(18em) rotate(-45deg); }
.deg135 { transform: rotate(135deg) translate(18em) rotate(-135deg); }
.deg180 { transform: translate(-18em); }
.deg225 { transform: rotate(225deg) translate(18em) rotate(-225deg); }
.deg315 { transform: rotate(315deg) translate(18em) rotate(-315deg); }

.circle-container a.deg45:hover, a.deg45:activate { img-size: 150%; }
```

I want to wrap mine images inside div's and position them to form the circle, so they become responsive.

Is that possible?

Please Help.
Tank you.

I am using bootstrap and html5boilerplate for this project.

I need to make this to be [responsive.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q0IH.jpg),  on smaller viewport it would look like this [image: on smaller viewport.]

Comment: could you please elaborate on "responsive"

Comment: want to make it responsive for smaller viewports, mobile, fablet, tablet, etc..

Comment: can you recreate your issue here https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I have edit mine question, you have two pictures, one for desktop version, and one for smaller viewports

Comment: Have you considered using [CSS Media queries](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) ? And I believe that misplaced css inside your html is there by mistake right?

Comment: Yes it is by mistake, I have consider it, but I am having a hard time wrapping it to be responsive, I am searching for the best way, can you elaborate, pls?

Comment: @subas_poudel, here the proper link for the [circle div](http://dabblet.com/gist/3864650)

Comment: I'll try to come up with a suggestion and need some time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check the JsFiddle I created for you https://jsfiddle.net/1et5s06h/ to check try to resize the preview pane.

FYI my answer depends on bootstrap's [Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and [Responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities). You may want to read them to get a better understanding of the grid system and responsive utility classes and to customize my answer to better fit into your needs.

Refer to the below code (that uses your css):

```
 <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="circle-container hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                <div class="row">
                    <span data-scrollreveal="enter top, wait 1.0s">
                        <a href="#" class="center hvr-grow">
                            <img src="http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2003-28-a-thumb.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </span>

                    <span data-scrollreveal="enter right, wait 1.2s">
                        <a href="#" class="deg0">
                            <img src="http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2003-28-a-thumb.jpg" class="img-circle" alt=""></a>
                    </span>

                    <span data-scrollreveal="enter right, wait 1.4s">
                        <a href="#" class="deg45">
                            <img src="http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2003-28-a-thumb.jpg" class="img-circle" alt=""></a>
                    </span>

                    <span data-scrollreveal="enter right, wait 1.6s">
                        <a href="#" class="deg135">
                            <img src="http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2003-28-a-thumb.jpg" class="img-circle" alt=""></a>
                    </span>

                    <span data-scrollreveal="enter left, wait 1.8s">
                        <a href="#" class="deg180">
                            <img src="http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2003-28-a-thumb.jpg" class="img-circle" alt=""></a>
                    </span>

                    <span data-scrollreveal="enter left, wait 2.0s">
                        <a href="#" class="deg225">
                            <img src="http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2003-28-a-thumb.jpg" class="img-circle" alt=""></a>
                    </span>

                    <span data-scrollreveal="enter left, wait 2.2s">
                        <a href="#" class="deg315">
                            <img src="http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2003-28-a-thumb.jpg" class="img-circle" alt=""></a>
                    </span>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!--end circle-container-->
            <div class='container hidden-lg hidden-md '>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <a href='#'>
                            <img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2003-28-a-thumb.jpg' class="img-circle" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <a href='#'>
                            <img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-1994-02-c-thumb.jpg' class="img-circle" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <a href='#'>
                            <img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2005-37-a-thumb.jpg' class="img-circle" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <a href='#'>
                            <img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2010-26-a-thumb.jpg' class="img-circle" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">Strange book here :)</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <a href='#'>
                            <img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2004-27-a-thumb.jpg' class="img-circle" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <a href='#'>
                            <img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-1992-17-a-thumb.jpg' class="img-circle" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <a href='#'>
                            <img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2004-32-d-thumb.jpg' class="img-circle" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <a href='#'>
                            <img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2004-32-d-thumb.jpg' class="img-circle" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Update:** I made a little enhancement [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1et5s06h/1/) that is to show grid interface only in extra small devices (xs) and centered the images within their containers by adding the following css:

```
div.container.hidden-lg.hidden-md.hidden-sm div.row div.col-sm-4.col-xs-4 a img.img-circle 
    {
         display:block;margin:10px auto;
    }
```

and I thought I'd better state the idea behind my answer more vivid: I basically create two instances of your content and using [responsive utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) I made your circle of images visible for:

- Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) (lg)
- Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) (md)
- Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) (sm)

and hide circle placement and made grid placement visible in:

- Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) (xs)

Of course, to emphasize again, my update note explains the altered code presented [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1et5s06h/1/).

Comment: tank you, I will inspect it as soon as possible.

Comment: Can you advise me, the best way to put mine paper.gif in the footrest of the picture, tnx for the example, I am using it for mine web site, I am juts going to change it a little.

Comment: I haven't seen a paper.gif image in your code, do you mean the book picture? And you're welcome, glad that I helped.

Comment: [this is it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q0IH.jpg), this is what i want to make on bigger screen, the paper is on the bootom, and I will put a jquery toogle() for it.

Comment: This seems like the subject of another question but to state a quick idea: you need to alter the src (or the css class that identifies the background image) as a quick search would give you [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057513/toggling-an-image-src-with-jquery)

Comment: Superb answer with nice explanation..!! +1

Comment: so, the bottom line is that I should approach this problem whit changing this images whit css background and jQuery, yes this is superb answer, tank you once again ~:)

Comment: Among all a lot of others, this is an option fro you to choose, thank you @Nadeem and you're welcome Petar Pilipovic.

Comment: @wooer, I have post a question about what I haved asked you, can you check mine [edit] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29506527/how-to-hover-change-toggle-a-picture-with-jquery/29508895#29508895), section.