# Implement jQuery slidedown effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery slide down animation, but I would like to implement it to the paste section bellow.

Content is for a smaller device so every button need to have slide down element attached on him self.

Can some one show me how can I do this.

Mine jQuery slideDown code:

```
$(".squere").click(function(){    
    $(".content").hide(800);
    $(".squere").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
$(this).next(".content").slideDown(1000);
});
```

Mine Content:

```
            <div id="squere" class='container hidden-lg hidden-md '>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <img class="img-responsive img-circle homepageGridDefault" src="img/circle/home-all-icon-off.png">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="img/circle/home-cover-icon-off.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="img/circle/home-diy-icon-off.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="img/circle/home-marketing-icon-off.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">Strange book here :)</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="img/circle/home-other-icon-off.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="img/circle/home-special-icon-off.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="img/circle/home-vip-icon-off.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="img/circle/home-designe-icon-off.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/copser/1et5s06h/6/) example, this is the whole dive and it is responsive so do not mind the upper circle in the html section.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle!!

Comment: you now have and fiddle example in mine question.

Comment: It's very difficult yo understand from your fiddle!! I assume that you want to show a `content` div for each `image` when clicked on it? Correct me if am wrong!!

Comment: Yes exactly that, show a div for each image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use sildeDown and slideUp can resolve your problem.Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1et5s06h/16/). Just used slideUp and slide Down method in place of adding and removing active class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.content').hide();
});

$(document).on('click',".center",function(){   
    $(".content").slideUp(300);
    $(this).next(".content").slideDown(300);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok. I've just modified your code and added just 3 images and a `content` div as below:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1et5s06h/8/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">

                   <a href="#" class="center">
                        <img src="http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2003-28-a-thumb.jpg" class="img-circle" alt=""/>
                   </a>
                   <div class="content">
                         Content Image 1
                   </div>

              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                   <a href="#" class="center">
                        <img src="http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-1994-02-c-thumb.jpg" class="img-circle" alt=""/>
                   </a>
                   <div class="content">
                        Content Image 2
                   </div>

               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                   <a href="#" class="center">
                        <img src="http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2005-37-a-thumb.jpg" class="img-circle" alt=""/>
                   </a>
                <div class="content">
                     Content Image 3
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.content').hide();
});

$(document).on('click',".center",function(){   
     if($(this).hasClass('active'))
     {
         return;
     }
    $(".content").hide(800);
    $(".center").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
     $(this).next(".content").show(1000);
});
```

**Note:** These are just basic animations. If you really want to perform some extra-ordinary animations then you need to check on **[`.animate` jquery](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)** function.

Comment: I have seen it and that is what I need, I will check the animation link, and make shure to implement this fore every image, just one thing, is it posibble to put an img inside a content, so when you click on it will unfold some paper i have designed.

Comment: Unclear!! can you be more specific!! inside what content you want to put image?? I think **image will always be displayed and only text has to be displayed based on the image clicked** was your problem right??

Comment: Ok I will. be more specific, I have design a scroll paper, and I want to put it inside mine div so it will slide up and down, and text to be displayed on it, just to change mine slider to be an image.

Comment: You can do it!! but am not sure how your design looks!! if you give some idea on you design or put it in fiddle I can definitely help you out!! :)

Comment: here this was the question for the desktop view animaton, you will see the picture, the paper scroll is in the middl. whit displayed text on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29506527/how-to-hover-change-toggle-a-picture-with-jquery?noredirect=1#comment47425983_29506527

Comment: Yes you can do it!!! But I am afraid that you can just `slideDown` the image paper which is in div and not give an exact feeling of unfold using this `slideDown`. That's where **`.animate`** comes into picture!! :)

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please use id selector `#` instead of class selector `.`

```
$("#squere").click(function(){    
    $(".content").hide(800);
    $("#squere").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
     $(this).next(".content").slideDown(1000);
});
```

Might be it is your issue.

```
$("#squere").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
```

These lines will not make any effect, because you are removing and adding same css class.

Comment: the problem is I do not know how to implement this, and I am trying to ask someone to show me so I can use it in mine project and learn something.