# Toggle Img Src on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have number of rows like this,

```
<tr class="row">
    <td class="optionsImg">
        <img src="../status/approved-01.png" />
        <img src="../status/rejected-01.png" />
        <img src="../status/pending-01.png" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

and JS,

```
    $("#myTable").on('click', "optionsImg img", function () {
        $(this).attr('src', this.src...);
    });
```

How can I toggle `approved-01 to approved-02` or `approved-02 to approved-01` and same for other images, i have both 2 sets of images, fade one finish with 01.png and colored ones with ..-02.png

Comment: when you want to toggle it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggling an image src with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057513/toggling-an-image-src-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#myTable").on('click', ".optionsImg img", function () {
        var currentSRC = $(this).attr('src');
        if(currentSRC.indexOf("-01")>-1)
        {
            currentSRC = currentSRC.replace("-01", "-02");
        }
        else
        {
            currentSRC = currentSRC.replace("-02", "-01");
        }
        $(this).attr('src', currentSRC );
    });
```