# Change image of specific clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to toggle the src of the specific image element clicked. But, only for that image. In other words, only toggle the one clicked. If clicked again then change back. How can I do this with jQuery or JavaScript. The code can be seen here: https://codepen.io/centem/pen/NgKEmG

```
<!-- 
When image clicked change image to:
https://www.centerpointe.com/v2/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/red-x.png
-->

<ul class="list-unstyled">

<li>Username<span class="pull-right">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png"></span><span class="pull-right">
<img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/firefox/firefox_PNG16.png"></span><span class="pull-right">
<img src="https://ma.ttias.be/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/internet-explorer-logo.png"></span></li>

<li>Username<span class="pull-right">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png"></span><span class="pull-right">
<img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/firefox/firefox_PNG16.png"></span><span class="pull-right">
<img src="https://ma.ttias.be/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/internet-explorer-logo.png"></span></li></li>

<li>Username<span class="pull-right">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png"></span><span class="pull-right">
<img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/firefox/firefox_PNG16.png"></span><span class="pull-right">
<img src="https://ma.ttias.be/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/internet-explorer-logo.png"></span></li></li>

</ul>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
    function handler( event ) {
  var target = $( event.target );
  if ( target.is( "img" ) ) {
    target.src().toggle(
"https://www.centerpointe.com/v2/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/red-x.png");
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically change the src of an img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag)

Comment: Your codepen makes $('.chrome').attr('src', ...), changing all $('.chrome'). Change to $('this).attr('src', ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `click` event on `img` that exist in ul and toggle `src` of them by saving in `data` attribute. For toggling you need to save main `src` of image that can be saved as `data-src` (or anything else), And you need a flag for state of image like `data-clicked` (or anything else).

```js
$('ul.list-unstyled li img').on('click', function(){
  var clicked = $(this).data('clicked');
  if(clicked === '1') {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('src'))
    $(this).data('clicked', '0')
  } else {
    $(this).data('src', $(this).attr('src'))
    $(this).attr('src', "https://www.centerpointe.com/v2/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/red-x.png");
    $(this).data('clicked', '1')
  }
})
```

```css
  img {
   height: 25px;
      padding-right: 4px;
  }
  li {
   margin: 4px;
      clear: both;
  }
  li:nth-child(odd) { 
   background: #f0f0f5; 
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 
When image clicked change image to:
https://www.centerpointe.com/v2/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/red-x.png
-->

<ul class="list-unstyled">

<li>Username<span class="pull-right">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png"></span><span class="pull-right">
<img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/firefox/firefox_PNG16.png"></span><span class="pull-right">
<img src="https://ma.ttias.be/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/internet-explorer-logo.png"></span></li>
 
<li>Username<span class="pull-right">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png"></span><span class="pull-right">
<img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/firefox/firefox_PNG16.png"></span><span class="pull-right">
<img src="https://ma.ttias.be/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/internet-explorer-logo.png"></span></li></li>

<li>Username<span class="pull-right">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png"></span><span class="pull-right">
<img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/firefox/firefox_PNG16.png"></span><span class="pull-right">
<img src="https://ma.ttias.be/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/internet-explorer-logo.png"></span></li></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you Mohammad! This works exactly how I was thinking it should work.I will practice applying this method.

Answer (score 0):

add an ID to your image and then try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#yourImage").onClick(function() { 
            $(this).attr("src", "https://www.centerpointe.com/v2/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/red-x.png");
        });
});
```

Alternatively, you can change the image depending on the source like this:

```
$(function() {
        $("img").onClick(function() { 
                if ($(this).attr("src") == "OriginalSource")
                    $(this).attr("src", "https://www.centerpointe.com/v2/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/red-x.png");
            });
    });
```

Comment: This is not really a good solution since you would need to add an `id` to every single image and have a dedicated click handler for each. Instead, I would suggest to use a selector that will match *any* `<img>` tag and then extract the clicked element from the click event.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is jquery's `attr()` function
Give your image a class name then you can change the src in jQuery by:

```
$(".image1").attr("src","https://www.centerpointe.com/v2/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/red-x.png");
```

And to attach it to a click event

```
$(".image1").click(function(){
    $('.image1').attr('src','https://www.centerpointe.com/v2/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/red-x.png');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Jay but how I do I prevent it from changing all of the images and toggle it back if clicked again.

Comment: Give the <img> tag a class or an id then use that to reference it from jquery, for toggling it back I found the answer here to be very useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057513/toggling-an-image-src-with-jquery